# Java full-screen exclusive mode and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, fullscreen, ubuntu-14.04

I have basic Java code to set a JFrame to full screen and change the display resolution.  This code is the same as the example code from Oracle's tutorials.

Everything works on Ubuntu 14.04 with the latest Java 7.0 and Java 8.0, but the title bar and menu bar are still displayed over the top of the full screen window.

Other answers suggest to enable "legacy full screen support" in the Compiz manager, but I have done this and nothing has changed.

Is there another workaround?

Link to example code: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/examples/MultiBufferTest.java

The example code uses a Frame and not a JFrame, but I haven't gotten either to work.

Comment: According to the author, frame.setUndecorated(true) is already in the code. It's Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an Ubuntu problem.  I've seen other posts about Minecraft showing the same behavior.  But those proposed fixes have not worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using JNA, the way I do this is:

```
private static final int _NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE = 0;

private static final int _NET_WM_STATE_ADD = 1;

private static final int TRUE = 1;

public static boolean setFullScreenWindow(Window w, boolean fullScreen) {
    X11 x = X11.INSTANCE;
    Display display = null;
    try {
        display = x.XOpenDisplay(null);
        int result = sendClientMessage(display, Native.getWindowID(w), "_NET_WM_STATE", new NativeLong(fullScreen ? _NET_WM_STATE_ADD : _NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE), x.XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN", false));
        return result != 0;
    }
    finally {
        if(display != null) {
            x.XCloseDisplay(display);
        }
    }
}

private static int sendClientMessage(Display display, long wid, String msg, NativeLong data0, NativeLong data1) {
    X11 x = X11.INSTANCE;
    XEvent event = new XEvent();
    event.type = X11.ClientMessage;
    event.setType(XClientMessageEvent.class);
    event.xclient.type = X11.ClientMessage;
    event.xclient.serial = new NativeLong(0L);
    event.xclient.send_event = TRUE;
    event.xclient.message_type = x.XInternAtom(display, msg, false);
    event.xclient.window = new com.sun.jna.platform.unix.X11.Window(wid);
    event.xclient.format = 32;
    event.xclient.data.setType(NativeLong[].class);
    event.xclient.data.l[0] = data0;
    event.xclient.data.l[1] = data1;
    event.xclient.data.l[2] = new NativeLong(0L);
    event.xclient.data.l[3] = new NativeLong(0L);
    event.xclient.data.l[4] = new NativeLong(0L);
    NativeLong mask = new NativeLong(X11.SubstructureRedirectMask | X11.SubstructureNotifyMask);
    int result = x.XSendEvent(display, x.XDefaultRootWindow(display), 0, mask, event);
    x.XFlush(display);
    return result;
}
```

You need to add the JNA and JNA Platform jar to your project.

This works for me on Kubuntu 14.10.

I originally wrote this code as part of my vlcj project here https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/vlcj-3.1.0/src/main/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/runtime/x/LibXUtil.java.

Comment: Wow.  I've never used JNA, only JNI with SWIG.  That looks interesting.  But I was sure hoping for something easier for a beginner to understand.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to get it to work with "pure" Java. For me, even on Windows, using a native call like this was the only way I could get it to behave how I wanted. If you're worried about it not being easy, just stick it in a utility class and forget about the implementation, it's not really that important to understand it.